# Access a BindingSource in one class from another class

Tags: c#, scope, bindingsource

I have 2 classes in the same project, ProjectView and FeatureView. I need to access a `BindingSource` in one class from another class. I have a kluge in which I make the `BindingSource` scope `internal` instead of `private`. Shame, shame. Is there a better way to do this?.

```
// ProjectView.cs
public partial class ProjectView : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl {

}

// ProjectView.Designer.cs
partial class ProjectView {
    // This should be private
    internal System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bsFeatures;
}  

// FeatureView.cs
public partial class FeatureView : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl { 

    // Get ProjectView
    Project currentProject = this._presenter.WorkItem.State["CurrentProject"] as Infrastructure.Interface.Aml.BusinessEntities.Project;
    string key = System.String.Concat("Project", currentProject.Id);
    this._presenter.WorkItem.State["CurrentProject"] = currentProject;
    ProjectView view = _presenter.WorkItem.Items.Get<ProjectView>(key);

    // Populate currentProject.Features with ProjectView.bsFeatures.List
    currentProject.Features.Clear();
    IList featureList = view.bsFeatures.List;
    foreach (Feature feature in featureList)
    {
        currentProject.Features.Add(feature);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like that, not sure:

```
    partial class ProjectView
{
    // This should be private
    private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bsFeatures;

    public System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource BindingSource
    {
        get { return bsFeatures; }
    }

    public void ShareOnlyWith(FeatureView  fw)
    {
        fw.BindingSource = bsFeatures;
    }
}
```

of course we break one of the principles, don't depend on concretions.